# unable to create and write to files in remote server using php

Tags: php

I am trying to create an html file in a remote server and write to it. My php script is in Linux server. I mounted remote server through below command.

```
    mount -t cifs <serverName> /var/www/html/f:  -o username=user
```

Now if I run my php code I am getting "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error. Php file has below code.

```
    $Folder = "/var/www/html/myserver/myfolder/" ;
    $result_file = $Folder . "myreport.html"; 
    $txt = "Some text\n";
    file_put_contents($result_file,$txt);
```

From the terminal I am able to connect to remote server and create file and also write to it. Issue is coming only when I run my php file.

Comment: Are you running your php script from the command line or through a web-server? In case of the latter, the web-server user (`apache`, `www`, etc.) needs write permissions.

Comment: i am running through a web-server. Can you tell me how can i  give write permissions? i tried the below.